# thicker axes in 3d plot

Tags: plotting, fonts

I am new to Mathematica, and am not able to figure out how to make the axes in a ListPlot3D plot thicker. For some reason assigning a larger value to FontSize doesn't do anything. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, 
 Mesh -> All, AxesStyle -> Thickness[.01]]
```

[image]

You can also style the three axes individually:

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}],  Mesh -> None,
 AxesStyle -> {Directive[{Red, Thick}],
   Directive[{Green, Thickness[.007]}],
   Directive[{Blue, Thickness[.01]}]}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

**Update:** To style the `Box`, add the option

```
BoxStyle -> Directive[{Orange, Thick}] (* say *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, do you also happen to know how to make the frame thicker as well?

Comment: Alex, add the option `BoxStyle -> Thick`.